# Select positive (or negative) values in GNU Octave

Tags: octave

I have a single column matrix of un-ordered signed values; e.g.:

```
values = [ -3; 0; 2; 3; -1; -2; 1 ];
```

How can I separate this into a positive and a negative matrix? i.e.,

```
values_neg = [ -3; -1; -2 ];
values_pos = [ 2; 3; 1 ];
```

I have tried looking for a way to specify an index; but, my GNU Octave-fu is quite limited at this point. I can find how to index entire rows or columns. Is there a way to specify constraints?

Comment: Basics of indexing: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html?refresh=true#MatrixIndexingExample-3):

```
values_pos = values(values > 0);
```